# Can linear independence be deduced before reduced matrix form?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the matrix below which represents a homogenous equation I need to conclude for which values of $m$ the system is linearly independent:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
2&-m&1 \\
1&-1&2 \\
-1&3&1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
After some elementary operations I get to the following form:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&-1&2 \\
0&2-m&-3 \\
0&2&3
\end{bmatrix}
$$

At this point if $m=4$ then we can see that the second row is equivalent to the third and is redundant and can become a row of zeroes ($Row_2 \to Row_2 + Row_3$). Therefore is it correct that I can already determine that for $m=4$ the system is linearly independent? Or the best practice is still to proceed to echelon form which is by the way:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&-1&2 \\
0&2&-3 \\
0&0&3m-12
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some sense, your observation about $Row_2 \to Row_2 + Row_3$ is precisely what the next stage in row reduction would give. In general, you don't need to go the entire way to Row Reduced Echelon Form, just far enough so that it is clear how you would get a row of zeroes. The definition of "clear" always depends on context.

If you're looking for a way to show linear (in)dependence, you can always look at the determinant as well. This is often easier with symbolic entries (I'm bad at adding $2m-3$ copies of one row to another). For this matrix, the determinant is $\det(A)= 12-3m$. The matrix has linearly independent rows/columns if and only if $\det(A) \neq 0$, so 
 \begin{align*}
 \det(A)=12-3m   &\neq 0 \\
 -3m &\neq -12 \\
 m &\neq 4
\end{align*}